# Python/Scapy - Timing KeyboardInterrupts

Tags: python, scapy, sniffing

I'm not sure if this is a possible thing to do but I am writing a two-sided program where Scapy's sniff() function sniffs for some time and then analyzes what it has been sent from the other host after I input a Control-C Keyboard Interrupt.  Then it sniffs some more until I Control-C and so on and so forth.  Is there some way that I can do:

```
sniff(icmpv6)
time.sleep(5)
python.KeyboardInterrupt()
analyze packets
...
...
sniff(icmpv6)
time.sleep(5)
python.KayboardInterrupt()
analyze more packets
...
...
The End
```

I haven't been able to find anything that can do such a thing.  Does anyone know of a way?

Comment: have you tried `while True: try: sniff_here() except KeyboardInterrupt: stop_sniffing()`?

Comment: But how do I code "KeyboardInterrupt"?

Comment: Do you want to raise `KeyboardInterrupt` yourself without pressing `Ctrl+C`? You could send `SIGINT` signal to the process.